# how do resolve soap object creation error?

Tags: php, web-services, magento, soap, wsdl

```
    public function connect($url,$username,$password){

    $proxy = new SoapClient($url); 
    $sessionId = $proxy->login($username,$password);        
    return $sessionId;

}
```

I get this error:

> object(SoapClient)#42 (2) { ["_soap_version"]=> int(1) ["sdl"]=>
>   resource(56) of type (Unknown) }

while runnnig my php script.how do solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, where is the code for it.

I believe this is how *soapClient object* looks after connection.

```
$functions = $soapClient->__getFunctions ();
var_dump ($functions);
```

Comment: @Karan: Please Share the php please. Its not possible to suggest in a generic way.

Comment: @Karan: Try my suggestion and see the outcome too. It should work

Comment: do you mean the whole module?

Comment: The way I am using the function. and also you go through [THIS](http://www.allwebdevhelp.com/php/help-tutorials.php?i=12960)